# My abstract class is sending output?

Tags: php, http-headers, abstract-class

I can not change headers because apparently my abstract class is starting output. Why would this be starting output? is it a bug with 5.4?

```
namespace Lume\Abstracts;
abstract class Chain{
    abstract protected static function GetSelf();//the line that is starting output
    abstract protected static function SetSelf();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably some whitespaces/newlines added before or after the PHP tags .

Try removing the closing tag ?> in case there is one.

If that doesn't help, post the exact error and file code, please.

Comment: I removed it and same error. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Chain.php:4) in Route.php on line 44. Route line 44 is where im trying to generate a 404 header.

Comment: The error is there because PHP is trying to modify the headers at that point - Chain.php is the file where you likely have whitespace or something else.